# Ajax call within ajax tab, use of on?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page, A, which on its own successfully makes ajax calls using the code below. But if page A is called by ajax as a tab by page B, the code does not work. How to fix? I know this is related to divs created virtually, but googling does not show how to use 'on' here or how to fix.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'hotel-avail.php', 
data:'querystring defining data',
success: function(data){
  $("#div<%=i%>").html(data);
}
});
```

I am assuming also that the linking to ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js should be in page B not A. Correct?

Comment: need more data, for example you HTML code.

Comment: The question is, what event is calling this code on page B? I'd be willing to bet that's where the real problems is.

Comment: @Amleonard, the ajax code above is in a recordset loop that produces a list of hotels. For each loop the code automatically fires and places the response on availability (yes or no) in the div giving details of the hotel. As such there is no event triggering it, just the loop. Works fine when page opened on own, not when opened as ajax tab in B.

Comment: Oh, well if I'm understanding you correctly, that's because jQuery doesn't run code in the HTML that is retrieved via AJAX. That is to say, if you get HTML from the AJAX request that contains a `<script>` tag, the javascript inside it will not be executed.

Comment: @Amleonard Yes - that is exactly the problem it seems.

Answer (score 0):

First check if jquery exists on page (inspect on chrome try find the ajax.googleapis...)
maybe you not implement the jquery on page B
If they have same layout that's ok but if not you should call again to  ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: Have now tried all combinations: 1) ajax.googleapis on both pages, 2) only on page A, 3) only page B. None work when page A called as tab by page B, page A on its own obviously not working with 3).